# How to make footer stay at bottom of the page with flex-box

Tags: html, css, flexbox

On iOS Safari when I create a div is a flex item and also make it a flex container, its height does not stretch to match its contents. However if it is not made a flex container then its height does stretch to match its contents.

To elaborate - I am using css flexbox to place a footer at the bottom of the page. The page body has two divs - "maincontents" and "footer". Even if the "maincontents" div has little or no content, the footer will still stay at the bottom of the window. And if the "maincontents" div has a lot of content, it can push the footer down as required. This idea was easily implemented in flexbox by making the page body a flex container, and setting "maincontents" to "flex:1" and "footer" to "flex:0", so that way "maincontents" takes up all available space while "footer" gets pushed to the bottom of the window. It works well on all modern browsers including iOS safari.

The problem arises if I also make "maincontents" a flexbox itself (using display:flex). On iOS Safari the footer now always stays at the bottom of the window, even if maincontents has a lot of content that should push the footer down further; instead "maincontents" ends up continuing underneath "footer" rather than pushing it down.

I have made a barebones mockup of this on jsfiddle. 
https://jsfiddle.net/8xs1rocu/

Here is what you would see if you open that fiddle on a window desktop (chrome/ff/ie11)
[image]

And here is what you would see if you open it on an ipad or iphone (safari).
[image]

**Notice that on iOS safari the footer does not get pushed down by the content, and the content instead ends up going under it**. This does NOT happen on Chrome/FF/IE11 on a desktop; on those browsers the footer is pushed down by the contents of "maincontents".

If you remove the "display:flex" line, then it works perfectly on ios safari too, just as it does on other browsers. However I need that "display:flex" line because I will be putting other content inside "maincontents" that needs to be laid out a certain way using css flexbox.

Pasting the jsfiddle snippet code directly here:

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.maincontents {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex; /* if you remove this line it works on Safari */
}

.footer {
  flex: 0;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <div class="maincontents">
      Main contents1 <br />
      Main contents2 <br />
      Main contents3 <br />
      Main contents4 <br />
      Main contents5 <br /> 
      Main contents6 <br />
      Main contents7 <br />
      Main contents8 <br />
      Main contents9 <br />
      Main contents10 <br />
      Main contents11 <br />
      Main contents12 <br />
    </div>
   
    <div class="footer">
      Footer1 <br />
      Footer2 <br />
      Footer3 <br />
      Footer4 <br />
      Footer5 <br />
      Footer6 <br />
      Footer7 <br />
    </div> 
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 23):

Just add `margin-top: auto;` to the footer.

That will cause it to stick to the bottom of its container.

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.maincontents {
    /* nothing to put here */
}

.footer {
  margin-top: auto;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <div class="maincontents">
      Main contents1 <br />
      Main contents2 <br />
      Main contents3 <br />
      Main contents4 <br />
      Main contents5 <br /> 
      Main contents6 <br />
      Main contents7 <br />
      Main contents8 <br />
      Main contents9 <br />
      Main contents10 <br />
      Main contents11 <br />
      Main contents12 <br />
    </div>
   
    <div class="footer">
      Footer1 <br />
      Footer2 <br />
      Footer3 <br />
      Footer4 <br />
      Footer5 <br />
      Footer6 <br />
      Footer7 <br />
    </div> 
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5):

For anyone looking for an alternative answer that doesn't require setting `margin-top: auto;` on your footer (you may want to set a top margin on your footer at some point, who knows), this has always worked great in my projects.

Assuming the following basic layout (`<main>` is equivalent to the OP's `.maincontents` in this case):

```
<html lang="en-US">
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <header></header>
    <main>Main content</main>
    <footer>Footer content<footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

Simply add the following CSS to your reset:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

main {   
    flex: 1 0 auto; 
}

footer {
    flex-shrink: 0;    
}
```

`flex-shrink: 0` overrides the default of 1 so the `<footer>` doesn't shrink while `flex: 1 0 auto;` allows `<main>` to grow to fit the rest of the available space.

Answer (score 3):

Upon further investigation I have found solution to your problem. With the information I hope you can make the following changes:

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.maincontents {
  min-height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: stretch;
}

.footer {
  flex: 0;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
  <div class="maincontents">
    Main contents1 <br />
    Main contents2 <br />
    Main contents3 <br />
    Main contents4 <br />
    Main contents5 <br /> 
    Main contents6 <br />
    Main contents7 <br />
    Main contents8 <br />
    Main contents9 <br />
    Main contents10 <br />
    Main contents11 <br />
    Main contents12 <br />
  </div>

  <div class="footer">
    Footer1 <br />
    Footer2 <br />
    Footer3 <br />
    Footer4 <br />
    Footer5 <br />
    Footer6 <br />
    Footer7 <br />
  </div>
  
</body>
</html>
```

I have tested on safari and Chrome and works as you expect. The following is a jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/1o3904xh/12/

I would highly recommend that anyone looking at this to make the footer stay at the bottom of the page and any content to remain above do it like the following way. This is correct semantics which provide increase SEO and accessibility. With this layout it should put you in a very good position for your web page.

You can read more about the HTML5 elements [here](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_semantic_elements.asp)

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

article {
  min-height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: stretch;
}

main {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

header, main, footer {
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.footer {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <article>
      <header></header>
      <main>
        <div class="maincontents">
          Main contents1 <br />
          Main contents2 <br />
          Main contents3 <br />
          Main contents4 <br />
          Main contents5 <br />
          Main contents6 <br />
          Main contents7 <br />
          Main contents8 <br />
          Main contents9 <br />
          Main contents10 <br />
          Main contents11 <br />
          Main contents12 <br />
          Main contents13 <br />
          Main contents14 <br />
          Main contents15 <br />
          Main contents16 <br />
        </div>
      </main>
      <footer>
        <div class="footer">
          Footer1 <br />
          Footer2 <br />
          Footer3 <br />
        </div>
      </footer>
    </article>
  </body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: How is this solving the issue OP has?

Comment: The problem was that the `mainContent` would not push the header to the bottom. In the above the footer remains at the bottom. He can have whatever content he wants in the `main` element (which he has said he intends to do). The above will also put him in a more beneficial place. I may be missing something here (which I apologise if I am) so please expand your point, but the above is what the OP ask for.

Comment: Here is a jsfiddle of the above https://jsfiddle.net/smtr083h/32/ .Seems to be working as how the OP wants the page to function. Footer at the bottom. Any content can then be used and footer will remain at bottom. When there is no space between content and footer, the content will not overlap the footer (as was previous problem).

Comment: Were you able to test this on Safari? That was the issue; it would work fine on Chrome/Firefox, but not on Safari

Comment: Corbuk, while your solution may work, it is a complete rewrite. The fiddle I created was only a simplified/barebones example of the issue, so it seems easy to just rewrite it completely. However the actual project already has existing code as well as parent layouts (into which the child page code gets injected), so I cannot actually change the whole structure of the page. It would help if you could explain why exactly this code works and the previous one doesn't, because then I can figure out what specific rules need to be tweaked without having to change everything.

Comment: Sorry there was no mention of the above information in original post, might be useful if you could include that in there? Also that may make thing more difficult, so only styles on `mainContainer` and `footer` can be touched? If this is true, please make a note of this in original post. I guess this is something your organisation should take note on. HTML5 elements increase SEO and accessibility. Will look into another solution with only touching the above two classes, but I will need time.

Comment: This really isn't an issue of HTML5, OP's markup is fine, yes could use `footer` and `main` tags, but those really have nothing to do with the issue; which is a CSS only thing... so don't sweat it too much on the tags used

Comment: I would disagree with you about the markup being fine. But that is besides the point.

Comment: Easy, I know the value of semantic tags, believe me, what I mean is that the use of those semantic tags have nothing to do with the issue, as you said thats for SEO and accessibility, which OP can implement if he *wants to*, the site will *render* fine either way... Now, can you try maybe moving the rules you used (`flex-grow`, `flex-shrink`, `align-items: stretch;`) to the containers already in place in OP's question instead? Can't test it on Safari unfortunately, but maybe that could work as mostly you created additional containers for those

Comment: I am sure you do, I guess I was trying to improve overall answer without considering if this is part of a greater application. Which was hard to guess by original post. Moving onto the point, what is weird if I remove the `display: flex` in `mainContent` it works fine in Safari AND Chrome, So I a unable to reproduce original problem. Which makes me wonder if OP is using emulator

Comment: Corbuk, that is exactly what I had said - if you remove the display:flex then it works perfectly in all browsers, whether desktop chrome/Firefox or iOS safari. No emulator required to see this. (So you have correctly reproduced what I see).

Comment: @gary what is problem then? If you're saying you want to create new `div` inside `mainContent` then you would use `display: flex` on that inner div not the `mainContent`.

Comment: Please read the last paragraph of the post. I need the display: flex, because in the actual project I will put additional stuff inside maincontent, which requires maincontent to be a flex container. That is in fact the core of this issue - why is putting display: flex on maincontent causing things to go wrong in safari, whereas everything is fine on chrome/Firefox/IE?

Comment: Sorry I am just trying to understand problem to try and help. It can be many issues. Is the CSS in `mainContent` all of the CSS, or has some been left out? Also inside `mainContainer` are there/can there be any other `div` HTML elements? Like this jsfiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/8n2zup9y/2/ .Also what is the structure of this content that requires flex?

Comment: Corbuk, no need to apologize, your help is appreciated. It is just that I have boiled the problem down to its simplest level, because the actual page contains many elements and will complicate the example. (The mainContainer itself needs to be a flex container, since it will have various different elements within it, but this will be different for different types of pages on the website, so no point mocking it in the example just yet). At its core the problem is very simple - the example works in FF/Chrome/IE, but not in iOS safari - and the display:flex has something to do with it.

Comment: I believe the issue is solved now. See the answer I posted a few minutes ago.

Comment: Glad problem has been solved :) Will leave answer as is because provides semantically correct way this should be done, plus alternative solution

Answer (score 0):

The solution to make this work in iOS Safari was to add a flex-shrink:0 to the `maincontents` div.

I changed

```
.maincontents {
     flex: 1;
     display: flex;
}
```

to

```
.maincontents {
     /* flex: 1*/       /* removed this */
     flex-grow: 1;      /* added this */
     flex-shrink: 0;    /* added this */
     display: flex;
}
```

To be honest I am not sure why this worked. The default flex-shrink value is flex-shrink:1. It would seem that in Safari if a div is both a flex item is also a flex container with flex-shrink:1, then the div will not stretch to fit its contents. This could be a Safari bug, as it does not happen in Firefox/Chrome/IE on a desktop, but it also appears on Opera on the desktop (which is quite odd since Opera uses the same rendering engine as Chrome, which does not have this issue). Maybe someone else can offer an explanation about why this tweak was necessary in Safari and Opera but not in Chrome, Firefox or IE.