# margin-top: auto, but minimum of 50px

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'd like to apply an auto top margin to my footer tag, but with a minimum of 50px of margin (it cannot be less than 50px). I've tried with the min() function in css, but I cannot solve the problem. I don't know if I am missing something or if there is another correct way to do this.

```css
* {
    --red: #f70000;
    --gold: #caa866;
    --blue: #004d96;
    --BGblue: #004d96ef;
    --white: rgb(230, 230, 230);
    --traswhite: rgba(235, 235, 235, 0.5);
    --black: rgb(20, 20, 20);
    --trasblack: rgba(20, 20, 20, 0.6);
    --warning: #CC3300;
}

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

html {
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

body {
    min-height: 100vh;
    background-color: var(--white);
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    transition: all ease-in-out 0.3s;
}

footer {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;

    margin-top: 50px;

    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;

    background-color: var(--black);

    transition: all ease-in-out 0.3s;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <p style="color: white">elements in the footer</p>
</footer>
```

Comment: a transparent top-border with 50px ?

Comment: _"but with a minimum of 50px of margin (it cannot be less than 50px)"_ - and based on _what_ exactly, should it become more ...? _"I've tried with the min() function in css, but I cannot solve the problem"_ - well that would require at least two "arguments". The 50px would be one of those - but what would be the other ...?

Comment: Please may you add a [mcve] so we can see what you've got so far? (Use a snippet. The `<>` button)

Comment: @TemaniAfif doesn't work for two main reasons: the first is that the border would be at the inside of my footer tag. The second is that if i would use an "outline" instead of a border (to draw it outside of the footer) it would go over the other elements in the page, without moving them. Thanks btw!

Comment: ... and that's why you should add a [mre] of your situation to begin with - so that we don't have to figure out why specific approaches might _not_ work, one by one, by you going "oh and here's another little thing I completely forgot to mention initially ..."

Comment: @CBroe the issue is that i have to stick the footer at the bottom of a page which is not full of "stuff". 'till this point no issue, it would be easy, but the problems comes when in this page there are buttons that make elements appear. So when theese elements appear i have to maintain the footer at the bottom, but with a 50px margin from the page content.

Comment: @evolutionxbox i'm going to do that in a few minutes, thanks for your help btw! (first time using stackoverflow to ask, so i'm kinda new of the features i can use!)

Comment: @evolutionxbox the snippet i've inserted is the rough summarization of what i have now in my footer css style file. If you need more i can insert also the body and html styles

Comment: You have shown us _just_ the footer now, so _what_ this is supposed to be kept at a certain minimum distance from, is still unclear.

Comment: @CBroe it has to keep a minimum of 50px from everything it is above it. In some cases is a button, in other cases is a span, in other cases is an img. If it could be helpfull i can send the whole page in the snippet.

Comment: I am guessing you want the very "classic" thing here, were the footer is always at the bottom of the screen, if there is only little main content, and gets pushed further down, if there is more? https://stackoverflow.com/a/55542885/1427878 - adding an additional margin-top in that should work without any problems.

Comment: @CBroe Your "guess" is right, but what do you mean with "additional margin-top"? If you mean to edit the snippet you linked me adding to the footer a "margin-top: 50px;" it doesn't work unfortunately. If you mean something else i didn't understand properly what you just explained :D

Comment: The second snippet in Corbuk's answer, with `margin-top: 50px` for `footer`, should do exactly what you want.

Comment: @CBroe unfortunately it does not, but i solved thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want the footer always be at the bottom of the page (and at least 50px away from the main content) else at the bottom of the viewport.

You can do this with `position:sticky` by setting the footer to be positioned 100% from top minus the footer height. EG:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: #eee;
}

section {
  border: 2px dotted red;
  padding: 10px;
}

footer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  position: sticky;
  top: calc(100% - 200px);
  height: 200px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<section contenteditable="true">
  I am content-editable. Type in here to simulate what happens with more page content.
</section>
<footer>
  elements in the footer
</footer>
```

Comment: yes, it was exactly what i needed thank you so much!! Can i ask what calc does? Thanks again!

Comment: The CSS Calc() function lets you perform calculations when specifying CSS property values. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc